# Laravel Seeder - iterate through an array within a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, for-loop, laravel-5.4

I want to seed a table's column, based on the IDs from another table's rows.

**Rows:**

```
$audits = Audit::where('audit_id', $auditScore->id)->pluck('id')->all();
```

Which returns an array of IDs (18 of them).

For each of the IDs within the above array, I want to add them to each of the results within the `with` relationship of the below result:

```
$reAudit = ReAuditScore::where('audit_score_id', $auditScore->id)
                         ->with('audits')
                         ->get();
```

How can I iterate through the array, and add the ID?

Comment: Can you clarify this `I want to add them to each of the results within the with relationship of the below result`.

Comment: So within `$reAudit->audits`, there is 18 results. I want to loop through those 18 results and add 1 ID from the `$audits` array (incrementing up as the loop continues).

Comment: Sorry. I must be being dense this morning. You can look through the `$reAudit->audits` using a `foreach` loop, or `each()` function on the collection. But when you say add "one ID` from the `$audits` array, add it how? Are you `attaching` it? Setting a property? Creating a new relationship?

Comment: No problem at all. I have a column within the `$reAudit->audits` named `audits_id`. I want to update that column with "one ID" from that array. So for example, it will iterate through the 18 `$reAudit->audits`, whilst iterating through the 18 IDs of the `$audits` array. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an incomplete answer, because I don't fully understand your requirements. However, it's easier to respond here than in comments.

Does something like this do what you require?
When iterating through the `$reAudit->audits`, you're going to need to make sure there are an equal number of `$auditIds`, or check for their existence before use.

```
$auditIds = Audit::where('audit_id', $auditScore->id)->pluck()->all();
$reAudit = ReAuditScore::where('audit_score_id', $auditScore->id)
    ->with('audits')
    ->get();

foreach ($reAudit->audits as $i => $audit) {
    if (! empty($auditIds[$i]) {
        $audit->update(['audit_id' => $auditIds[$i]]);
    }
}
```

Or to approach it from the other direction:

```
$auditIds = Audit::where('audit_id', $auditScore->id)->pluck()->all();
$reAudit = ReAuditScore::where('audit_score_id', $auditScore->id)
    ->with('audits')
    ->get();

foreach ($auditIds as $i => $auditId) {
    if (! ($audit = $reAudit->audits->get($i))) break;
    $audit->update(['audit_id' => $auditId]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @fubar.